# Google URL Shortener returns error, {"domain"=>"usageLimits", > "reason"=>"ipRefererBlocked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-url-shortener

I'd like to use [google url shortener](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started) on ruby.
I've been using [googl](https://github.com/zigotto/googl).
At the google developer console, I've got an api key. I've set the ip address "127.0.0.1".

Then, I wrote as following, however it returned an error.
Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

```
Googl.shorten('url',"127.0.0.1",my_api_key)
```

> Googl::Error ({"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"usageLimits",
>   "reason"=>"ipRefererBlocked", "message"=>"There is a per-IP or
>   per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request
>   does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers
>   Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP
>   or referer should be allowed.",
>   "extendedHelp"=>"https://console.developers.google.com"}],
>   "code"=>403, "message"=>"There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction
>   configured on your API key and the request does not match these
>   restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your
>   API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be
>   allowed."}}):   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:102:in `create'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a google developer console, if I made api key not specifying ip address, it didn't return error. But I'm still not sure why it returns error when it is specified ip address.

Comment: You also need to specify key parameter in your request.